# View does not display the content loaded through main view in controller (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created two views ('main' and 'home_view'). Through a controller called 'Home' I load home_view through main view. But the result is not what I had written on the "home_view". Here below are my pages:

1. home_view:

   `<h1>Hello, from home_view </h1>`
2. Home Controller contains the following code:

   `<?php
     class Home extends CI_Controller 
      {
        public function index ()
         {
            $data['main_view']="home_view";
            $this->load->view('Layouts/main',$data); 
         }
      }
    ?>`
3. Main view. I created a folder in View folder called "Layouts"  then in that folder I created "main" view. The Main view contains the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meter charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  

 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-9">
    <?php $this->load->view($main_view); ?>
   
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJIY.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YGX7.png

altering the statement in the controller I get the results but still, that object is visible:

```
`$data['main_view']= $this->load->view('home_view');
 $this->load->view('Layouts/main',$data);`
```

[the screenshot after altering in the controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJIY.png)

Comment: What result are you essentially getting then ?

Comment: @DaniyalNasir I have added the result screenshot

Comment: Just for testing place `home_view` inside layouts and check if this render your view

Comment: Even by doing what you have advised I  get the same result.

Comment: In your controller  try replacing `$data['main_view']="home_view"` with   `$data['main_view']="views/home_view"`

Comment: still not working. please see the edits I brought in the question and see the second screen shot

Comment: so, you're not getting your main_view rendered , right ?

Comment: is your home_view.php located directly in views? or in a sub folder?

Comment: @Muhmaad, yeah the home_view is directly located in the view folder.

Comment: @user3027490 I re-produce your scenario in my CI application having layout inside **`views/layouts/main`** and its content inside  **`views/home_view`**.  IT IS **WORKING** FOR ME

Answer (score 0):

I was avoiding to suggest you to load the view in advance and pass to the other view first, but since nothing seems to work for you. Do like this in your controller:

```
<?php
    // the "TRUE" argument tells it to return the content, rather than display it immediately
    $data['main_view'] = $this->load->view('home_view', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->view ('Layouts/main', $data);
?>
```

Then put `<?= $main_view ?>` in your view at the point you want the menu to appear.

**WARNING:** *When you pass a view this way (with the TRUE parameter ) you are converting all your view content into a string. This works most of the time, but once you have heavy data, or perhaps when you are passing arrays or JSON. it needs to be handled.*

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting no output but a bar, was typo error. In the heading section of the 'Main'view:

```html
<meter charset="utf-8" >

I should have written this one:

<meta charset="utf-8">
```

"